# How to post data to a external database using Name Value pair and http Url Connection?

Tags: android

I have not got any proper code to send data to external database in `API level 23` as `HTTP client` method is deprecated. Please help me. I am Stuck here from a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `StringRequest`, example:

```
public static JSONObject sendRequestGetReserves(RequestQueue requestQueue)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException, JSONException {


    JSONObject response = null;

    RequestFuture<String> requestFuture = RequestFuture.newFuture();

    StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "Your url", requestFuture, requestFuture) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Your NameValuePair1", "value1");
            params.put("Your NameValuePair2", "value2");
            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(strRequest);

    response = new JSONObject(requestFuture.get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

    return response;
}
```